# How can I retrieve FormData (HtmlFormElement) data from Javascript in Razor PageModel?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, base64, croppie

I'm trying to send a base64 string to my Razor PageModel using ajax. The base64 string is the result of a Croppie result. Any help would be greatly appreciate. I've tried the following ways:

1) **Creating a FormData form and sending that to my PageModel:**

```
        var f = new FormData();
        f.append('s',base64)

        $.ajax({
            url: "?handler=SaveIcon",
            data: f
        });
```

**Result:**

```
        jquery.js:8463 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Illegal invocation
        at add (jquery.js:8463)
        at buildParams (jquery.js:8450)
        at Function.jQuery.param (jquery.js:8483)
        at Function.ajax (jquery.js:9073)
        at ChangeProfilePhoto:205
```

2) **Passing the base64 string directly through ajax:**

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "?handler=SaveIcon",
            data: { 's': base64 }
        });
```

**Result:** URI Too Long

3) **Sending the base64 string through post:**

```
        var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
        var headers = {};
        headers['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token;

        var f = new FormData();
        f.append('s', base64);

        $.ajax({
            headers: headers,
            url: "?handler=SaveIcon",
            method: "POST",
            data: f,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
```

**Result:** 400 Bad Request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `processData` and `contentType` parameters to `false`

```
var f = new FormData();
f.append('s',base64)

$.ajax({
    url: "?handler=SaveIcon",
    method: "post",
    data: f,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

In order to pass antiforgery token via headers use default header name (if not configured other) `RequestVerificationToken` (without leading underscores)

```
var headers = {
    RequestVerificationToken: token
};
```

Or you can pass it as `FormData` as well

```
var f = new FormData();
f.append('s',base64);
f.append("__RequestVerificationToken", token);
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm receiving a 400 Bad Request error even though I added a token on the header of the ajax call.

Comment: @SalS Please add your `c#` action code to question, so I can investigate this issue